# COMO REALIZAR UNA FUNCIÓN QUE ALMACENE LOS DATOS DE UN ARCHIVO EN UNA ESTRUCTURA

Tags: c

Tengo un ejercicio que dice: añadir una función (a un código que ya tengo) que almacene todos los datos en una estructura. La estructura DatosEmpregos debe tener un campo de código de país, campos para la fecha inicial y final, y un campo por cada serie y así almacenar todos los datos del país en el intervalo temporal en el que fueron recogidos. Guardar finalmente todos los datos en un archivo binario .dat

No sé como almacenar los datos en una estructura ni sé como pasar el archivo a binario.

El .txt del que tengo que sacar los datos es:

```
AUT,"SL.EMP.WORK.MA.ZS","84.4329986572266","84.3659973144531","84.1809997558594","83.8990020751953","84.4290008544922","84.6210021972656","84.4349975585938","84.2229995727539","84.6520004272461","84.8759994506836"
AUT,"SL.EMP.WORK.FE.ZS","88.5070037841797","88.8740005493164","88.822998046875","88.7649993896484","89.2959976196289","89.4909973144531","89.4240036010742","89.4530029296875","89.5899963378906","89.9300003051758"
AUT,"SL.EMP.VULN.MA.ZS","8.8089998960495","9.18799996376038","9.21899998188019","9.43900012969971","8.92999982833862","8.75099980831146","9.12099981307983","9.02999985218048","9.00500011444092","8.78099989891052"
AUT,"SL.EMP.VULN.FE.ZS","8.84800004959107","8.49899983406067","8.56699967384338","8.60800004005433","8.24500012397766","8.14999985694885","8.29199993610382","8.11700010299683","7.94199991226196","7.52400016784668"
AUT,"SL.UEM.TOTL.FE.ZS","5.30200004577637","4.41200017929077","5.08400011062622","4.63100004196167","4.57600021362305","4.79500007629395","5.28700017929077","5.38000011444092","5.30399990081787","5.53599977493286"
AUT,"SL.UEM.TOTL.MA.ZS","4.49100017547607","3.89199995994568","5.48400020599365","4.98199987411499","4.5460000038147","4.93499994277954","5.36700010299683","5.82999992370605","6.08400011062622","6.42600011825562"
AUT,"SL.EMP.SELF.FE.ZS","11.4930000305176","11.1260004043579","11.1770000457764","11.2349996566772","10.7040004730225","10.5089998245239","10.576000213623","10.5469999313354","10.4099998474121","10.0699996948242"
AUT,"SL.EMP.SELF.MA.ZS","15.5670003890991","15.6339998245239","15.8190002441406","16.1009998321533","15.5710000991821","15.378999710083","15.5649995803833","15.7770004272461","15.3479995727539","15.1239995956421"
AUT,"SL.UEM.ADVN.FE.ZS","2.25889992713928","1.67009997367859","2.09999990463257","2.30170011520386","2.16960000991821","2.03290009498596","2.84299993515015","3.75250005722046","4.00470018386841","3.77069997787476"
AUT,"SL.UEM.ADVN.MA.ZS","2.71050000190735","1.86769998073578","2.59509992599487","2.52769994735718","2.5961000919342","2.3775999546051","3.44479990005493","3.95020008087158","3.87319993972778","3.58010005950928"
,"","","","","","","","","","",""
,"","","","","","","","","","",""
,"","","","","","","","","","",""
Data from Database: Empleos,"","","","","","","","","","",""
Last Updated: 04/08/2022,"","","","","","","","","","",""
```

y el código que tengo es:

```
void gardar_datos(FILE *ff);

typedef struct {

    int ano[10];
    char pais;
    char serie;

}DatosEmpregos;

int main() {

    FILE *fich;
    if ((fich = fopen("C:\\Users\\pedro\\Desktop\\untitled10\\AUT_jobs_2007_2016.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("\n\nNon foi posible abrir o ficheiro. \n\n");
    }
    else {
        gardar_datos(fich);
    }
}

void xera_txt (FILE *ff) {

    FILE *arc;

    if ((ff = fopen("C:\\Users\\pedro\\Desktop\\untitled10\\AUT_jobs_2007_2016.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("\n\nNon foi posible abrir o ficheiro. \n\n");
    } else {

        DatosEmpregos Datos;
        

    }


    fclose(ff);
    fclose (arc);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero hay que crear una estructura valida en la que se pueda guardar un registro de los datos del fichero de entrada:

```
typedef struct {

    int ano_ini;//p.e 2007
    int ano_fin;//p.e 2016

    char pais[3];//p.e:AUT
    char nombre_serie[17];//p.e SL.UEM.ADVN.FE.ZS
    float serie[10];// pe [2.71050000190735,...,3.58010005950928]

} DatosEmpregos;
```

En esta registro o estructura guardamos los datos de una serie que corresponde con una fila del archivo de entrada.

Comment: Ya tengo nuevos avances, pero no sé como seguir. Me recoge mal el primer numero de serie por un problema con la cadena al coger el país y me falta meter los datos en la estructura. El código que tengo ahora mismo no me deja puvlicarlo aqui pero voy a hacer otra pregunta en mi perfil por si me puedes ayudar. Gracias